# How to avoid javac warning: unknown enum constant, reason: class file not found, when dependency has optional annotations with enums

Tags: java, annotations, javac

I have this example setup:

**`p.E`**

```java
package p;

public enum E { E }
```

**`p.A`**

```java
package p;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface A {
    p.E e();
}
```

**`q.Test`**

```java
package q;

import p.*;

@A(e = E.E)
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test.main()");
    }
}
```

So, I can now do this:

```
$ javac q/Test.java
$ rm p/*.class
$ ll */*
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukas 197609 118 Mar 28 10:21 p/A.java
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukas 197609  32 Mar 28 09:43 p/E.java
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukas 197609 486 Mar 28 10:22 q/Test.class
-rw-r--r-- 1 lukas 197609 153 Mar 28 09:55 q/Test.java
$ java q/Test
Test.main()
```

No problem, the annotations are optional and ignored by the runtime, no `NoClassDefFoundError`

However, when I remove the source files of `p` as well, keeping the compiled `Test.class`:

```
$ rm -Rf p
```

And then create:

**`x.Test2`**

```java
package x;

public class Test2 {
    q.Test test;
}
```

Compiling that class gives a warning:

```
$ javac x/Test2.java
warning: unknown enum constant E.E
  reason: class file for p.E not found
1 warning
```

### Alternatives, that don't produce such a warning

#### No enum

I don't get this warning for an annotation that doesn't depend on any enums. I.e. repeat the procedure for these, and there's no warning:

**`p.A`**

```java
package p;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface A {}
```

**`q.Test`**

```java
package q;

import p.*;

@A
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test.main()");
    }
}
```

#### Class reference

When `A` references `Class<E>` instead of an `E.E` enum value, I still don't get any warnings:

**`p.A`**

```java
package p;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface A {
    Class<?> a();
}
```

**`q.Test`**

```java
package q;

import p.*;

@A(a = E.class)
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test.main()");
    }
}
```

### My questions:

1. Is this a correct warning according to the JLS? It seems like a bug in javac to me, given the annotation is optional and doesn't produce a warning if there's no `enum` type involved, but I may be missing something.
2. Is there any way to work around this warning in client code?

**For context: the real world use-case is:**

- The `p` package containing the annotations are from JAXB
- The `q` package containing library code that references the annotations is a library whose dependency on `p` is optional. (jOOQ to be specific, [more details here](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14865))
- The `x` package is client code, depending on the `q` package, which has an optional dependency on `p`, meaning, the dependency is effectively missing by default.

Comment: Why do you think the problem lies in javac and not java itself ? I mean, you only used javac to compile it in the beginning, java is the one that worked with different contexts.

Comment: @YassinHajaj: I asserted (just like that!) that the Right Thing™ to do here is to ignore this missing enum reference. A user of `x` (running `java`) can't really do much about it anyway, whereas a user of `q` (running `javac`) might still be able to fix things by adding a dependency.

Comment: Indeed, I read through some of the information here. Thanks for the additional information, it indeed can only be `javac`

Comment: I found a probably related bug report https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6550655 mentioned "If a completion failure is thrown when entering an annotation through ClassReader, a **warning** is issued.". So the warning is intentional.
I don't think JLS said anything about warnings during compiling.

Comment: @yyyy: Great finding! I wonder if it was implemented wrongly. There's a claim that *"but C.java is successfully compiled, and C.class correctly seems to contain the @B annotation. Probably some added warning is in order in case A.class could be found but A$E.class could not."* - The test in your linked issue only removed the enum, not the annotation, in case of which I agree with the warning. If both are removed, then I don't see the point of the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [commented by user yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75864102/how-to-avoid-javac-warning-unknown-enum-constant-reason-class-file-not-found?noredirect=1#comment133841351_75864102) and also on the [library bug tracker](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14865#issuecomment-1489310283), the current behaviour is defined by a fix [JDK-6550655](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6550655), which introduced the warning in Java 7 (before, this annotation/enum usage resulted in a compilation error).

[JDK-6550655](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6550655) is slightly different. The warning was introduced for cases where only the enum `p.E` is absent, not the annotation `p.A`, in case of which, indeed, undesired runtime errors will occur when accessing `p.A` using reflection API. Warning developers of this situation is certainly desired. In this case here, however, all content of the `p` package is absent, meaning there can't be any runtime errors, and the absence should be fine as per the design of annotations, which are allowed to be absent.

In my opinion, this is a bug in javac, which I've reported: [JDK-8305250](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8305250). It may or may not be accepted or fixed.

Comment: Current behavior probably exists before jdk-6550655, as you can see the "suggested fix" shows `if (enumerator == null) { log.error("unknown.enum.constant") ...`, which prints the warning you see, already exists before this fix.
I'd like to see the code history, but it's long before OpenJDK migrating to GitHub, I can't find the history anywhere.